# Passing an array as a parameter to Nelmio Alice fixture generator

Tags: php, fixtures

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to pass an empty array to a method using Alice fixture generator

So if I have a class like

```
class User
{
    private function __construct($name, array $images)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->images = $images
    }

    public static function create($name, array $images)
    {
        return self::create($name, $images);
    } 
}
```

How can i call this in Alice? I tried with empty array brackets but it only recognises that as a string

```
Namespace\Model\User:
  user{1..10}:
    __construct: { create: [ @identity<current()>, [] ] }
```

Comment: Why do you think you can even use an array as part of the fixture data? Please provide reference on which you base your assumption, otherwise people would create tons of questions here on SO just out of the blue. You need to make this much more concrete, otherwise this is no programming question. So please share, why should that work at all?

Comment: Why do you think that you can't? That's not a very helpful comment is it. And i dont think the question deserves to be marked down tbh. In the documentation it makes reference to passing an array in other circumstances `https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/master/README.md#multiple-references` so I think its a reasonable question to ask on here. Not every feature of tools is always documented, sometimes it's implied, and SO is exactly the place to ask people who might have detailed knowledge

Comment: And have you contacted the vendor for clarification already or is it just that you didn't do any research before asking? And it's not me who needs to outline that arrays are not possible. That belongs in the area of the person who asks the question. Provide as much information as possible regarding the concrete issue. Not my fault if it's not documented (I dunno but from your question it sounded that you didn't refer to any specs which is most often not constructive, not my fault if you don't have docs at hand, you probably want to sponsor the project to change that).

Comment: This sounds like a legitimate question to me, not sure why it's received that way... I specifically don't understand why it's been voted 3 times to close as *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic*: the OP did not ask for any recommendation, but just how to perform a given task using a given library.

Comment: Don't know if it is due to a new Version of Alice but the above fixtures code works for me using empty square brackets for an empty array. But there is a recursion issue in your above code, I think the create method code should rather read like `return new self($name, $images);`.